# weird behaviour with nested mappings

Tags: scala

I have a nested methods that performs couple of actions inside of it, and im getting some weird behaviour.

this is the method:

```
 def performAction(request: RequestModel): Future[ResponseModel] = {
// addToDb returns a Future[ObjectId]
    myService1.addToDb(request.user, request.time) flatMap {
      case objID: ObjectId =>
// doSomething returning ResponseModel
        myService2.doSomething(request) map {
// SuccessModel is extending ResponseModel
          case successData: SuccessModel =>
            successData
// FailureModel is extending ResponseModel
          case failureData: FailureModel =>
            myService1.removeFromDb(objID)
            failureData
        }
      case _ => throw new Exception("future failed")
    }
  }
```

in my tests I have mocks for all the inner service calls to control the return data.

and I want to test the case where I get `FailureModel`

the weird thing is that if i try to debug before `myService2.doSomething` objId is fine, but if I debug it after, lets say at `myService1.removeFromDb` objId will be equal to the return type(FailureModel)...why is that?

i can literally see in the debugger `objId = FailureModel(x,y,z)`

now i know tht because the mappings im mapping the objId to be something else but never seen it in the debugger like this, does that make sense?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? 

Is your `removeFromDb` function not working properly due to objId somehow mutating?

 Or does your code work and you are specifically curious about what your debugger is doing?

Comment: @Charles curious about what my debugger is doing

Comment: Can you add more information about your debugger then? What debugger is it? Can you provide the value in question at each step with screenshots from your debugger?